# How do I safely display the HTML content of a received email in a Rails app?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, html-email

In a Rails app, I'm receiving emails via POST request from Mailgun and then saving them to the database. One of the attributes being saved is the stringified HTML content of the email message. I'd like to display this HTML in a view, with its original formatting (or close to it).

How can safely convert and render this HTML, without opening myself up to an XSS attack?

So far I've tried:

- `<%= lead_email.html %>` -  just displays the raw HTML markup as a string.
- `<%= raw lead_email.html %>` - renders the HTML, looks great, but I'm not protected.
- `<%= sanitize lead_email.html %>` - removes way too many tags. I tried specifying tags to keep in the sanitize method, but it seems to be having problems with `<!-- comments -->` as well.

Comment: https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize#allow_comments-boolean

Comment: You can pass a custom whitelist or create your own scrubber for [`sanitize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html).